# Disable 'The value 'xxx' is not valid for 'yyy' message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a form and I'm using a ViewModel, so the ModelBinder can bind to my Strongly Typed Class. I'm using DataAnnotations for validation

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeValue {get;set;}

    [Range(0, 10, ErrorMessage="Enter a number between 0 and 10.")]
    public byte? SomeOtherValue {get;set;}

}
```

This works great. The problem however is when the user doesn't enter a valid value for the SomeOtherValue (like abc), a standard MVC-error pops up: 'The value 'abc' is not valid for 'SomeOtherValue'. This is really annoying, as I can't customize this message. I know there are ways to Localize this message, but that just doesn't make sense (I don't want a general message, I want a value-specific value).

I tried applying a RegularExpression-attribute to the 'SomeOtherValue', which only allows byte-values, but probably the standard-validation 'overrides' this validation. Is there some way to apply a custom 'the value is not valid' message for a property, or otherwise disable the standard-message?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different (non-ideal way, IMHO) to fix it if the custom validation attribute is not working for you. In the controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string fieldName = "ThatFieldName";
    var m = ViewData.ModelState[fieldName];

    if (m != null && m.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        ViewData.ModelState.Remove(fieldName);
        ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(fieldName, "You mucked that field up.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, this will replace all errors for that field with that message... you can do extra checks and only replace the error if it starts with "the value", etc.